# How to specify install location for electron app on windows using squirrel

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, squirrel.windows

A task I have at my work is to let the user decide the location/drive they want the windows app to install on. The app is built using electron. Upon googling I found out about squirrel and it seems like this tool will help me solve my problem but for the life of me I can't understand how to use it. The app uses squirrel.windows to package for windows but thats all I know. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unluckily, as far as I know, you're out of luck, since it's a design decision by squirrel.windows to don't allow to choose where to install the package. Further reading: https://github.com/Aluxian/electron-windows-installer/issues/11 . MAYBE, and I'm saying maybe, you may find a workaround through the MSI installer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-wix-msi

by setting

```
{
    ...
    ui: {
        "enabled": true,
        "chooseDirectory": true
    }
}
```